# How to position the react flatpickr inside a container instead of body

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, flatpickr

I am having a use case where i have to position the react flatpickr on the left or right side of the input element instead of above or below.

When using the flatpickr i noticed that the flatpickr gets added to the body of dom. Instead i want to add it to container div. so I am passing the appendTo option with container HTMLElement as value. But its not working as expected and still appending to the body tag.*

here is the code snippet i used.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr';

const DateFilter = props => {
    const {setDateTime} = props;
    const containerRef = useRef() ;
    const container = containerRef.current;

    return (
        <div ref={containerRef}>
            <Flatpickr
                appendTo={container}
                onChange={date => setDateTime(date)}
                enableTime={false}
                dateFormat={"Y-m-d"}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default DateFilter;
```

The calendar still gets added to the body.

[Contianer DOM post page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNTNn.png)

Clearly i am doing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found why it was not appending by inspecting the 
 1. React flatpicker Index.js
 2. Core flatpicker.js files

The options (appendTo) wasn't received in react-flatpickr because it should be passed inside an object and not as a direct value.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr';

const DateFilter = props => {
const {setDateTime} = props;
const containerRef = useRef() ;
const container = containerRef.current;

const getOptions = () => {
     return {
        appendTo : container,
        enableTime : false,
        dateFormat : "Y-m-d"
    }
}

return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
        <Flatpickr
            onChange={date => setDateTime(date)}
            options={getOptions()}
        />
    </div>
)
}

export default DateFilter;
```

And also make sure you pass the correct HTMLElement on the first render. Else if you pass undefined it will still load it in Body.

Comment: has problems with typescript..